# F# type information

Tags: types, f#, f#-interactive, f#-scripting

this simple function

```
let s =
    function
    | [] -> [[]]
    | list -> []::list
```

has type ('a List List -> 'a List List). Thus, since 'a is generic, it accepts lists af arbitrary depth as argument. My problem is that I always have to specify the depth of the input list or F# interactive will complain. e.g.

```
s []
```

will not work while

```
s ([]: int List List)
```

will. Similarly,

```
s [[[]]]
```

won't work but

```
s ([[[]]]:int List List List)
```

does.
So, this being just an example, is there any way to avoid such explicit typing in general?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [F# Take a list of lists and reverse all the sub-lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705131/f-take-a-list-of-lists-and-reverse-all-the-sub-lists)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem.  What is the type of

```
s [[[]]]
```

it is `'t list list`.  Due to some underlying .NET limitations, such a value can't exist.  You need to make `'t` concrete.

There are many excellent tutorials on F# value restriction out there, and the best solution is to just use your result later in the same file or provide some other way for inference to work to provide a concrete type.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with .NET limitations - it's fundamentally unsafe to support both generic values and mutation.